# Fixed element jumps on scroll in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript

I have an element fixed at the bottom right corner of the window. In chrome, it works fine, in firefox and IE, there is a jumpy effect. 
Here is the code I'm trying:

```
<div style="height: 300px;"></div>
<div class="test" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 77px; background-color: #333;"></div>
<div style="height: 1300px;"></div>

    $(window).scroll(function () { 
        var bHeight = $(window).height();
        var offset = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('.test').css({
            top: bHeight + offset - 77 + 'px';
        });

});
```

Ex Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ecx7zp9/6/ in chrome works fine, but IE and firefox, there is a bouncy effect on scroll. Could anyone please suggest a solution for this as I could not find anything? 
Thanks in advance for your help

Thanks,Akila

Answer (score 1):

So I hope I understand your question right.
You want to fix an element at the bottom?

You just can use css

```
.test
   {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
   }
```

Comment: It should stick to the bottom of the window, even on page scroll. So i cant give bottom = 0, it should take the scroll offset into account as shown in the code.

Comment: Make sure that you have removed **position: absolute** in your style attribute and the JS part => http://jsfiddle.net/3ecx7zp9/137/

Comment: Thanks for your response. In my case, this  fixed element is place inside a <section> which is absolutely positioned and giving bottom=0 is making it stick to the bottom of the page (not the window)